# Instantiating Object as Class Member C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class called `Employee` and class called `BenefitPackage`. I want `BenefitPackage` to be an attribute of `Employee`.  The program consists of a header file with classes and prototypes, a definitions.cpp file that contains the definitions for the prototypes and a source.cpp that contains the main function.

I cannot get it to compile.

Here is what I have, thanks in advance:

Header File:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class iEmployee {
public:
    virtual double calculatePay() = 0;
};
class Employee:public iEmployee {
protected:

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    char gender;
    int dependents;
    double annualSalary;
    BenefitPackage _benefitPackage;

public:

    static int numEmployees;

    static void getEmployees() 
    {
        // gets employees up to 1000
        bool done = false;
        int empCount = 0;
        Employee employees[1000];
        do {
            Employee::numEmployees++;
            employees[empCount].setInfo();
            employees[empCount].displayAll();

        } while (done!=true && empCount < 1000);
    }

    // Below are prototypes for Employee Methods

    Employee();

    Employee(string, string, char, int, double);

    double calculatePay();

    void displayEmployee();

    void setInfo();

    string getFirstName();

    void setFirstName();

    string getLastName();

    void setLastName();

    char getGender();

    void setGender();

    int getDependents();

    void setDependents();

    void setDependents(string);

    double getAnnualSalary();

    void setAnnualSalary();

    void setAnnualSalary(string);

    void displayAll();

    static int getNumEmployees();

};

class BenefitPackage {
protected:
    string healthInsurance;
    double lifeInsurance;
    int vacation;
public:
    BenefitPackage();
    BenefitPackage(string,double,int);
    void displayBenefits();
    string getHealthInsurance();
    void setHealthInsurance(string);
    double getLifeInsurance();
    void setLifeInsurance(double);
    int getVacation();
    void setVacation(int);
};
```

Definitions.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
//================Below are the Definitions for the Employee Methods====================================//

    Employee::Employee():_benefitPackage(){
        firstName = "not given";
        lastName = "not given";
        gender = 'U';
        dependents = 0;
        annualSalary = 20000;       
    }
    // Construct Employee with Parameters to define attributes
    Employee::Employee(string first, string last, char gen, int dep, double salary):gender(gen),lastName(last),dependents(dep),annualSalary(salary),_benefitPackage(){};

    // Calculate Pay : Annual Salary / 52
    double Employee::calculatePay() {
        double payRate;
        payRate = annualSalary /52;
        return payRate;
    }
    // Display attributes of object
    void Employee::displayEmployee() {
        cout << "\nFirst Name: " << firstName;
        cout << "\nLast Name: " << lastName;
        cout << "\nGender: " << gender;
        cout << "\nDependents: " << dependents;
        cout << "\nSalary:\t " << setprecision(2)<<showpoint<<fixed<<annualSalary;
        cout << "\nBenefits:\n";//benefit.displayBenefits();
    }
    void Employee::setInfo() {

        setFirstName();
        setLastName();
        setGender();
        setDependents();
        setAnnualSalary();

    }
    string Employee::getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    void Employee::setFirstName() {
        cout << "\nEnter First Name: ";
        getline(cin,firstName);
    }
    string Employee::getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    void Employee::setLastName() {
        cout << "\nEnter Last Name: ";
        getline(cin,lastName);
    }
    char Employee::getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    void Employee::setGender() {
        string tempGen;
        cout << "\nEnter Gender: ";
        getline(cin, tempGen);
        gender = tempGen[0];
    }
    int Employee::getDependents() {
        return dependents;
    }
    void Employee::setDependents() {
        string tempDep;
        cout << "\nEnter Dependents: ";
        getline(cin,tempDep);
        dependents = atoi(tempDep.c_str());
    }
    void Employee::setDependents(string dep) {
        this->dependents = atoi(dep.c_str());
    }
    double Employee::getAnnualSalary() {
        return annualSalary;
    }
    void Employee::setAnnualSalary() {
        string tempSal;
        cout << "\nEnter Salary: ";
        getline(cin,tempSal);
        annualSalary = atof(tempSal.c_str());
    }
    void Employee::setAnnualSalary(string sal) {
        this->annualSalary = atof(sal.c_str());
    }
    void Employee::displayAll() {
        cout << "\n ***Employee "<<numEmployees<<" Information*** \n\n"<<"First Name: "<<firstName<<"\nLast Name: "<<lastName<<"\nGender: "<<gender<<"\nDependents: "<<dependents<<"\nSalary: "<<annualSalary<<"\n\n";
    }

    // initialize numEmployees to 0
int Employee::numEmployees = 0;

//================Below are the Definitions for the BenefitPackage Methods====================================//

// Default Constructor
BenefitPackage::BenefitPackage(){};
// Overloaded Constructor
BenefitPackage::BenefitPackage(string healthInsurance,double lifeInsurance,int vacation):healthInsurance(healthInsurance),lifeInsurance(lifeInsurance),vacation(vacation){};

void BenefitPackage::displayBenefits()
{
    cout << "\n\nHealth Insurance: "<<healthInsurance<<"\n\nLife Insurance: "<<lifeInsurance<<"\n\nVacation: "<<vacation<<"\n\n";
};
string BenefitPackage::getHealthInsurance()
{
    return healthInsurance;
};
void BenefitPackage::setHealthInsurance(string health)
{
    healthInsurance = health;
};
double BenefitPackage::getLifeInsurance()
{
    return lifeInsurance;
};
void BenefitPackage::setLifeInsurance(double life)
{
    lifeInsurance = life;
};
int BenefitPackage::getVacation()
{
    return vacation;
};
void BenefitPackage::setVacation(int vac)
{
    vacation = vac;
};
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

void main() {       
    Employee::getEmployees();   
}
```

Log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 10/8/2013 6:40:22 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\ConsoleApplication1.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\header.h(19): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_benefitPackage'
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\header.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  Definitions.cpp
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\header.h(19): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '_benefitPackage'
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\header.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\definitions.cpp(4): error C2614: 'Employee' : illegal member initialization: '_benefitPackage' is not a base or member
1>c:\users\me\downloads\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\definitions.cpp(12): error C2614: 'Employee' : illegal member initialization: '_benefitPackage' is not a base or member
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.41
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The compiler gives you the error message, why don't you use that to fix the problem?

Comment: Don't worry, we all make stupid mistakes. I have rollback the question since you cannot delete a question once it has been answered. This way others will at least be able to learn from your question.

Comment: @OpenLearner, thanks you are right, others may learn from this.  I'm used to javascript and just learning C++, so wasn't aware that order mattered.

Comment: I'm actually going in reverse, I've known C++ for a while and now I'm learning JavaScript. I was so surprised at just how free-form and non-strict JavaScript is. Definitely going from JavaScript to C++ you're going to encounter a lot of strict requirements in the language

Comment: @Happy I definitely tried to figure out the problem from the compiler errors and was unable to do so. I would actually be genuinely eager to hear your process of how you would break down the errors and trace them to the issue.

Comment: The compiler errors made it obvious to me what the problem was, because the benefit package type was simply not being recognized, and the compiler was trying to find other reasons for the issue. So that made me wonder why isn't the benefit package being recognized? So I looked up top and saw that there was no reference to this type anywhere above your class you were using it.

Comment: @OpenLearner, good to know.  Yeah javascript is so forgiving.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language, like python, while C++ is a very strict compiled language, and these two worlds of languages are very different. That is why interpreted languages tend to feel more forgiving, because they will always run right out of the gate, and any parts of them that do not run don't throw errors even if they are full of mistakes. But you don't get that in C++, which I think is a good thing. Generally leads to fewer crashes.

Comment: @OpenLearner, thanks for sharing your thought process regarding the compiler errors.  Also, regarding C++, I think that's why learning C++ will make me a better programmer overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, move your definition of your benefit package class above the other class definition so the compiler knows what the benefit package is when it encounters it as a type in your other class definition.

Alternately, separate them into separate header files, as that will make your project much more organized.